# Plot Labels on ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting

Is it possible to get more control of the plot labels with the PlotLayout->"Row" method for ListContourPlot? At the moment I'm getting a single label above the centre of the row. I'd like two separate labels above each plot.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please add Mathematica code to make this question more concrete. If you want your plot to look a certain way, you can edit the image of the plot with a paint.exe or gimp type software. Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there has been no response from the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
ListLinePlot[{{1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 9, 7}, {5, 6, 5, 4, 5, 7, 5}}, 
 PlotLayout -> "Row", 
 PlotLabels -> {Style["Plot1", FontSize -> 12], 
   Style["Plot2", FontSize -> 12]}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

Unfortunately ListContourPlot does not have the option PlotLabels. But we can do it "by hand":

```
pl1 = ListContourPlot[
   Table[x^2 + y^2, {x, -1, 1, 0.1}, {y, -1, 1, 0.1}], 
   PlotLabel -> "Plot1"];
pl2 = ListContourPlot[
   Table[x^3 + y^2, {x, -1, 1, 0.1}, {y, -1, 1, 0.1}], 
   PlotLabel -> "Plot2"];
Row[{pl1, pl2}]
```

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what I want, but its not an option for listcontourplot

Comment: Look at my answer. I added the code for ListContourPlot